# How focus invalid item in form Array

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

how to focus an invalid item in the form array,

Tried below with nativeElement focus , not getting exact invalid control.

```
 if (this.basicForm.invalid) {
        const invalid = [];
        const controls = this.basicForm.controls;
         for (const key of Object.keys(this.basicForm.controls)) {
           if (this.basicForm.controls[key].invalid) {
     
            const invalidControl = 
               this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('[formcontrolName="' + key + '"]');
               invalidControl.focus();
                break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML part where you are binding the formControlName directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can not use .querySelector('[formcontrolName="' + key + '"]')

I suggest use a directive to focus the invalid field

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusOnError]'
})
export class FocusOnErrorDirective {

  @ContentChildren(NgControl, { descendants: true }) fields: QueryList<NgControl>

  @HostListener('submit')
  check() {
    const fields = this.fields.toArray();
    //here we can use 
    //console.log(field) to know how "reach" the nativeElement
    for (let field of fields) {
      if (field.invalid) {
        const nativeElement = field.valueAccessor && (field.valueAccessor as any)._elementRef ? 
                (field.valueAccessor as any)._elementRef.nativeElement : null;
        if (nativeElement) {
          nativeElement.focus();
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, the only is adding the directive to the `<form>`, e.g.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" focusOnError (submit)="submit(form)">
 ...
</form>
```

You can see an example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdturb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffocus-on-error.directive.ts)

**Update** if we has a complex element (a custom formControl, or, e.g. a ng-autocomplete from angular-ng-autocomplete) we need "reach" the nativeElement.

In the case of angular-ng-autocomplete, we "reach" the nativeElement using

```
(field.valueAccessor as any).searchInput.nativeElement
```

I discovered that you reach the nativeElement using console.log(field) and see in console the object

So, we can improve our directive take account this

```
  check() {
    const fields = this.fields.toArray();
    for (let field of fields) {
      if (field.invalid) {
        const nativeElement =field.valueAccessor?
            (field.valueAccessor as any)._elementRef? 
                   (field.valueAccessor as any)._elementRef.nativeElement
            : (field.valueAccessor as any).searchInput? 
                   (field.valueAccessor as any).searchInput.nativeElement
            : null:
            null;

        if (nativeElement) {
          nativeElement.focus();
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

see that first ask about field.valueAccessor, if exist ask about field.valueAccessor._elementRef if not exist ask about field.valueAccessor.searchInput if not exist the null

Comment: Thanks, its working fine with , form array input controls, how to focus  <ng-autocomplete class="w-100"
                            #autoComplete1
                              [data]="types"
                             formControlName="JTyp"
                               ></ng-autocomplete>

Comment: @BasilJacob, I don't know about your ng-autocomplete (ther'e are severals librarys that has an ng-autocomplete component). I update the response to improve the directive if you're using `angular-ng-autocomplete` and indicate how we can improve the directive

Comment: yes i'm using  npm - angular-ng-autocomplete.

Comment: This was really helpful, though I had to add another condition for `ngbDatePicker` as follows: `field.valueAccessor && (field.valueAccessor as any)._elRef`. One thing I noticed is that I was unable to get the  element reference if there was a `mask` set on the field because the `valueAccessor` would return a `MaskDirective` with no way to get element. Do you have a workaround?